# How to get this type of TAB hairline movement

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-tabhost

I want to get this type of TAB hairline movement. I am using Action Sherlock Bar in my application's every Tab Activity. I am giving images hope you understand better! I want that when i swipe from 1 Tab Activity to another Tab Activity my hairline over Ta b activity also moves with the tab movement

See i added a capture here In this tab hairline as shown in red box 2nd capture:
[image]

Comment: [PagerSlidingTabStrip](https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip)

Comment: Now there is new way http://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-working-with-tabs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Widget like slider tab indicator which is compatible with `ViewPager` in android.

Include the PagerSlidingTabStrip widget in your view. This should usually be placed adjacent to the ViewPager it represents.

```
<com.astuetz.viewpager.extensions.PagerSlidingTabStrip
android:id="@+id/tabs"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="48dip" />
```

In your onCreate method (or onCreateView for a fragment), bind the widget to the ViewPager.

```
 // Set the pager with an adapter
 ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
 pager.setAdapter(new TestAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
 // Bind the widget to the adapter
  PagerSlidingTabStrip tabs = (PagerSlidingTabStrip) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
  tabs.setViewPager(pager);
```

Check out [Sample](https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip)

Comment: Hi @GrlsHU, can we integrated this library with navigation Drawer? I have a problem with that, because in this library we need extends from `FragmentActivty`, but with navigation drawer we need `ActionBarActivity`, if I change `FragmentActivity` to `ActionBarActivity` error happened for changing my Theme to `AppCompat`, but as my minimum SDK version is 8 i can't use `ActionBar` in that, can you guide me?

Comment: @shayanpourvatan `ActionBar` is implemented above the api level 8. If you want to use `ActionBarActivity` then you also have to add its supporting library in your project. Check out http://hmkcode.com/add-actionbar-to-android-2-3-x/ it will help you.