# Actionbar Tabs Indicator slide

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-viewpager, scrollview

How can I have fixed tabs with a sliding tab indicator like described here:

[How to get this type of TAB hairline movement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18268495/how-to-get-this-type-of-tab-hairline-movement)

http://www.pushing-pixels.org/2013/05/09/android-bits-and-pieces-sliding-tabs-madness.html

& here

http://viewpagerindicator.com/

using as much stock android as possible. But the important part is FIXED, I dont want tabs that looks like they are in a scrollview like all these examples have. And preferably with icons and not text.

Comment: So you want tabs to be swipe-able? Or just that the transition between them shows them swiping?

Comment: I want the indicator, the little line under the title of each tab to slide. Like in all example I posted links to above. 
Swipe between the tabs them selves should work as well, but I already have that working.

Comment: Ah, you just want to have the line indicating which tab is currently selected. That is done via `theme` or `style`. Do you use your own theme or a native one?

Comment: I have an indicator line already, but I want it to slide when I slide between the tabs. Check the first link above please. Now it just makes a jump for me with no transition. I want the indicator itself to slide.

Comment: Now that is a good question ;)

Answer (score 0):

As for stock android solution, I assume you could use HorizontalScrollView at the top of your container (just below the ActionBar) and use `SmoothScrollTo(int x, int y)` method with `x` and `y` coordinates obtained from your ActionBar. But that's just the beginning, you'd have to do a lot of modification. 
There's also an Apache 2.0 licensed library @ github that already did all those modifications for you so you might [use it](https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip) instead.

Comment: Thanks, but this one like the other ones doesn't have fixed tabs. Maybe I have to do it the long way like you described.

Comment: Perhaps you can extend his library to use with fixed tabs instead of writing it all over again.

Answer (score 0):

Use https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip and .setShouldExpand(true)

As long as your tabs would normally fit in the parent width (screen width), then you'll get fixed tabs with an animated tab indicator.